# How do I clear login history

Tags: osx-lion

In OSX, I can get login history and account usage :

- The command `ac -p` gives total login time of users on a machine.
- The command `last` gives history of login on the machine.

How do I reset these informations?

Documentation points to `/var/run/utmpx` but erasing the file has no apparent effect.
Directory `/var/account/` which should contain a lot of interesting stuff does not exist either.

### Update:

After stumbling on the `opensnoop` command, I found out that the history is stored in `/var/log/asl/*.asl`. Deleting these files does the job.

Comment: Even if you find a solution yourself, please post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login information is stored in the Apple System Log.

Erasing `/var/log/asl/*.asl` clears the log files containing (among other things) the login history.